# onLocationChanged(Location location) is not working - Android

Tags: android, android-gps

I have used `manager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 1800000, 1, new LocationDetector());` method of `LocationManager manager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);` class for getting update when either location change (device's location) is at least 1 meter (almost 40 inches), **OR** at least 30 minutes has passed. But the update is not being received when I change device's location by 1 meter (or even more). So what can be the problem? Please tell.

**Code:**

```
public class LocationDetector implements LocationListener {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d("GPS: ",location.getLatitude()+", "+location.getLongitude());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not **OR**, it's **AND**.

To get a location update with those parameters the distance needs to change at least 1 meter AND 30 minutes needs to have passed since the previous update.

[Android documentation:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent))

> The minDistance parameter can also be used to control the frequency of
>   location updates. If it is greater than 0 then the location provider
>   will only send your application an update when the location has
>   changed by at least minDistance meters, AND at least minTime
>   milliseconds have passed.

Comment: but the update is being received after 30 minutes without change in location of device.

Comment: Like said [in here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37094660/requestlocationupdates-method-is-giving-updates-without-change-in-location-a/37097663#37097663) there probably is a change in the location as GPS coordinates can fluctuate even for a device lying perfectly still.