# onLocationChanged() is never trigered by requestLocationUpdate() - Android

Tags: android, android-gps

I have used `manager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 1000, 0, new LocationDetector());` to get update after every second. But this method is never triggering `onLocationChanged()` method. I have run my application many times, and I have also tried to wait up to 30 minutes for getting update, but no update is being displayed on Android Monitor. I have also double checked my device's GPS which is ON. So Kindly tell what can be the problem?

**Code:**

```
public class LocationDetector implements LocationListener {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d("GPS: ", location.getLatitude()+ ", " +location.getLongitude());
    }
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: the onLocationChanged() function only gets called when your location changes. Have you tried changing your position to trigger this?

Comment: You can use https://www.genymotion.com/ to give it mock locations so you don't have to physically move to test the `onLocationChanged()` function

Comment: I have set `minimum distance = 0` inside `requestLocationUpdates()` which means update will be generated after 1 second even if change in location is 0 meters. @Chepe77

Comment: Do you have the correct permissions? Check this answer , the problem seems similar : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447861/onlocationchanged-is-not-called-automatically

Comment: Where is the code when you are actually requesting location?

Comment: `manager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 1000, 0, new LocationDetector());` @SmitPatel

Comment: i made changes to my answer. give it a try

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37095377/onlocationchangedlocation-location-is-not-working-android?rq=1), also asked by you. In any case, you could try using `GoogleAPIClient` - like this:

```
    LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setInterval(60000); // update every (1) minutes               
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient,locationRequest, yourLocationDetector );
```

Where the googleApiClient is instantiated and connected in some helper method like this:

```
/**
     * Helper method to connect the Google API Client
     */
    private void connectGoogleAPIClient() {
      googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                                .build();
      googleApiClient.connect();
    }
```

You also need to make sure you have added the permission:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />`

Your problem might be related to the [one discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447861/onlocationchanged-is-not-called-automatically?lq=1) - so please also look at the selected answer there and see if it does not help your case as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is what a typical location request should look like:

Note: I have `Activity` as a parameter because I call this from an Activity. It is in my util class.

```
public static void getLocation(Activity activity) {
    final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onProviderEnabled");
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onProviderDisabled");
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onLocationChanged");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onStatusChanged");
        }
    };

    final LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) appContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    final Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    criteria.setCostAllowed(false);
    criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
    criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
    criteria.setSpeedRequired(false);

    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(1000, 0, criteria, locationListener, null);
        }
    });
}
```

EDIT:
like @ishmaelMakitla said,

make sure to have the following permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```