# requestLocationUpdates() takes too much time OR it does not works at all

Tags: android, android-gps

I have used `requestLocationUpdates` method inside `Service` in my Android application for getting updates whenever location of my device changes. I have set `minTime = 0` But this `requestLocationUpdates` method is giving update after very long delays (that is 10 to 15 minutes, or even more). And sometimes when I run my application `requestLocationUpdates` mehod does not gives any update at all. And few of the times (very rare) this `requestLocationUpdates` method behaves as expected (gives updates continuously with 0 seconds delay). So what can be the problem? And how can I get updates continuously, every time when I run my application?

**HelloService.java**

```
public class HelloService extends Service {
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Handler(getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.context, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.context, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            return;
                        }
                        else {
                            manager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 0, 0, new LocationDetector());
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.ctx, "Service Started...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

**LocationDetector.java**

```
public class LocationDetector implements LocationListener {    
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        /*I have used here Log.e instead of Log.d in order to get the output in clear red message that is easily readable*/
        Log.e("GPS: ", location.getLatitude()+ ", " +location.getLongitude(), new Exception());
    }
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
}
```

Comment: you request location manager returns you location every 0 second and every 0 meters. so what behavior you actually expect?

Comment: Go outside where GPS actually works.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37103136/onlocationchanged-is-never-trigered-by-requestlocationupdate-android). You have pretty much started to spam Stack Overflow now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your whole code with creating new project in my laptop and run on my phone.

Result : It's working and GPS TTF is almost 15 seconds on my phone.

Have you tried other devices ?

What about gps icon ? appeared, disappeared ?

And try fused location provider to see what gonna happen, [link](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Retrieving-Location-with-LocationServices-API)

Comment: are you getting an update after every second, every time you run your application?

Comment: i'm getting location updates with different period because it's not working well with aggressively usage like minTime = 0 and minDistance = 0.

Comment: what is the maximum delay between two updates you have observed in your execution?

Comment: after first fix(15 seconds), delay was between 0 - 2000 millis.

Comment: I have waited up to 30 minutes , but no update has been received. gps icon is appearing. So is it a problem in device's gps?

Comment: It's hard to say directly your gps device has problem. I think you should try different devices. And depends on where you stay, go outside or balcony.

Comment: should I use `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER` instead of `"gps"`?

Comment: should I use `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER` instead of `"gps"`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111466/discussion-between-blackkara-and-sajal-ali).

Answer (score 0):

I hade the same problem and I fixed it by using `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER` as first argument for `requestLocationUpdates` instead of `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER` (in your question you use `"gps"`, which is the same thing as `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER`).

So my working code looks like this:

```java
manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
```